# Difference between a Row and its lead by 3 Rows in a dask dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, shift

I have a `CSV` file which has been imported as a dask dataframe through the following codes:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("name and path of the file.csv")
df.head(10)
```

output

```
+-----+------+-----+
|col1 | col2 | col3|
+-----+------+-----+    
|  A  |  2   |  4  |
+-----+------+-----+    
|  A  |  4   |  5  | 
+-----+------+-----+    
|  A  |  7   |  7  | 
+-----+------+-----+    
|  A  |  3   |  8  | 
+-----+------+-----+    
|  A  |  7   |  3  | 
+-----+------+-----+    
|  B  |  8   |  9  |
+-----+------+-----+    
|  B  |  10  |  10 | 
+-----+------+-----+    
|  B  |  8   |  9  |
+-----+------+-----+    
|  B  |  20  |  15 |
+-----+------+-----+
```

I want to create another column `col4` which contains `col2[n+3]/col2-1` for each group in col1 separately.

The output should be

```
   +-----+------+-----+-----+
   |col1 | col2 | col3| col4|
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    2 |   4 |  0.5|  #(3/2-1)
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    4 |   5 | 0.75| #(7/4-1)
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    7 |   7 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    3 |   8 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | A   |    7 |   3 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | B   |    8 |   9 | 1.5 |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | B   |   10 |  10 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | B   |    8 |  9  |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+    
   | B   |   20 |  15 |  NA |
   +-----+------+-----+-----+
```

We can do this task on pandas as follows

```
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(-3)) / df['col2'] - 1
```

but it does not work in dask. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The diff method has now been added to both DataFrame and Series, in this PR: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/1769. Works the same as it does in pandas.

moreover I am just asking you to use diff where you can just provide the Index

I guess there is already a task to implement Shift() with dask .... i have provided the link above ... i hope that will answer you questions

Comment: Thank you, but there is nothing on the page to answer my question. It would be helpful if you could provide me with some sample codes